# What does "screenSize" in Android Manifest do?

Tags: java, android

Hello I have got an Activity, where I have multiple Fragments inside, where AsyncTasks are running. My current problem is, when I change the orientation of device, while AsyncTask is doin stuff, App is crashing. As far as I could read from some threats, the addigin "screenSize" like:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
```

should solve that problem. But now, my app is crashing every time I change the orientation - what does screenSize exactly do, and why is my app crashing while changing its orientation?

edit: is there any special thing I have to give attention while using screenSize concerning my fragments - so the app does not crash?

thank u

Comment: Start by reading the developer docs, in particular http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

See this link for your error: https://gist.github.com/daichan4649/2480065

If you don't want to re-create the fragment on `OnCreate`, you should use `setRetainInstance(true)` as described in the link.